# Column names in R

Tags: r

I have such a code here, is it possible to set the column names when combining? I have tried various methods but without success.

```r
data <- iris
a <- data[data$Species=='setosa', 1]
b <- data[data$Species == 'versicolor', 1]
c <- data[data$Species == 'virginica', 1]

#ldply(list(setosa, versicolor, virginica), summary)

result <- data.frame(cbind(as.matrix(summary(a)),as.matrix(summary(b)), as.matrix(summary(c))))
colnames(result) <- c('setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica')
result
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with a named `list`

```
library(purrr)
imap_dfc(list(setosa = a, versicolor = b, virginica = c), 
   ~ setNames(as.data.frame(as.matrix(summary(.x))), .y))
```

Comment: What's .x and .y?